# Error allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, virtual-directory

recently while working on asp.net application, i got below error:

```
It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
```

i am sure the previous day it was working absolutely fine, however i guess this error occurs usually because of multiple web.config files, but i checked in my project, whole project contains single web.config files, can anyone please tell me what could be the reason for this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggests, You need to set up the directory you've placed the website in as a web application within IIS.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nawaaz, i got the resolution, actually that was because `i was opening website (using file-->open-->website) and not the solution`, so i opened the solution and cleaned the solution and build it, and worked properly, thanks a lot for taking time to revert.